# The fastest way to get a url inside a string

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have to check thousands of strings, I need to get the complete url that contains `instagram.com/p/`

So far I'm using this method:

```
msg ='hello there http://instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/'
msg = re.findall(
            'http[s]?://?[\w/\-?=%.]+instagram.com/p/(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+',
            msg)
print(msg)
```

but there are certain urls that it cannot find.

I want to get all urls that are like the following:

`https://instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/`
`https://www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/`
`http://instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/`
`https://www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/`
`www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/`

How can I obtain this result in the fastest way possible?

Comment: why not just capture everything after http and then feed that result in to urlparser in the stdlib to make sure it’s a valid url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = '''
'hello there http://google.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/ this is a test',
      'hello there https://www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/',
      'hello there www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/ this is a test',
      'hello there https://www.instagram.net/p/BvluRHRhN16/ this is a test'
'''

from urlextract import URLExtract

extractor = URLExtract()
urls = extractor.find_urls(url)
print(urls)
```

Output :
['http://google.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/', 'www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/', 'https://www.instagram.net/p/BvluRHRhN16/']

Edited : Filter the url's

```
filtered = ([item for item in urls if "instagram.com/p/" in item])

print(filtered)
```

Output : 
['https://www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/', 'www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/']

Comment: He's not trying to extract all URLs. Only specific URL as his intention.

Comment: Edited the above answer to filter the context path that's required.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the input is a list of sentences contain URL. Hope this can help.

```
msg =['hello there http://google.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/ this is a test',
      'hello there https://www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/',
      'hello there www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/ this is a test',
      'hello there https://www.instagram.net/p/BvluRHRhN16/ this is a test'
     ]

for m in msg:
    ms = re.findall('(http.*instagram.+\/p.+|www.*instagram.+\/p.+)',m)
    print(ms)
```

**Edited regex:**

```
ms = re.findall('(http.*instagram\.com\/p.+\/|www.*instagram\.com\/p.+\/)',m)
```

Comment: This will return all text after the url as well. For example, "hello there www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/ this is a test" returns: "www.instagram.com/p/BvluRHRhN16/ this is a test"

Comment: Hello, I tried to substitute `instagram` with `google` and it prints the google link as well, It shouldn't.. There is another way?

Comment: @Yusufsn This works pretty good, but the problem that I'm facing with your solution is: if after the link there is a space and then a word, it prints the word as well, for example if the sting is `https://www.instagram.com/p/BvnyDjXnHl5/ hello there` it prints the link plus hello there

Comment: I tried on my machine, it works as same as your intention. See and change the regex into the edited version. If the input is `https://www.instagram.com/p/BvnyDjXnHl5/ hello there` then the output will be `https://www.instagram.com/p/BvnyDjXnHl5/`

Comment: @Yusufsn I tried on my machine and even online but I get the `hello there` after the link, try to go and check online at https://repl.it/repls/BoringFlakyInfinity

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli you didn't change to the edited regex. Refresh this page, then you can see the edited version. Change into `(http.*instagram\.com\/p.+\/|www.*instagram\.com\/p.+\/)` as I have written in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. Thankyou for the answer! Have a great day!

Comment: With my pleasure. Happy to help.